# Replace every nth occurrence of 'foo' with the nth consecutive regular range of lines from a given file

Tags: string, bash, replace, text-processing

I would like to replace each `nth` occurrence of `foo` on the `1.txt` file with the nth consecutive *regular range of lines every nth lines* (**say in this case every 2 lines**) from the `0.txt` file containing the following content below (this is MWE).

source file is **0.txt:**

```
The sun has its own light
foo
The moon reflects the sunlight
foo
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
foo
```

target file is **1.txt:**

```
source-text1
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
source-text-2
[(('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))]
source-text-3
[(('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))]
```

Applying the replacement, e.g. 'command_method' 0.txt 1.txt > 2.txt , pseudocode, I would have the desired output file is as below, being the printed output on a third `2.txt` file:

**expected output is 2.txt:**

```
The sun has its own light
source-text1
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
The moon reflects the sunlight
source-text-2
[(('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))]
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
source-text-3
[(('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))]
```

I tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} /foo/{gsub("foo", a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2])} 1' 1.txt 0.txt > 2.txt
```

but this gives me **2.txt**:

```
The sun has its own light
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
The moon reflects the sunlight
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
source-text-2
```

I don't have ideas anymore. I'm looking for a solution that can work with any size range of lines

Comment: will `foo` always be on a line by itself? if not, please update the question to show the expected output if the input line is `foo bar`; what happens if you use up the replacements from `1.txt` (eg, `0.txt` has 3x `foo` entries but `1.txt` only have 4 lines)? how do you determine the number of spaces to indent the replacements ... always 5 spaces, or same indentation as the `foo` string?

Comment: @markp-fuso `foo` will always be isolated on a single line;  I would use the same amount of spaces for indentation as `foo` already has indentation (note: I just realized now that I accidentally indented `2.txt`, it was a mistake)

Comment: @markp-fuso I already updated the question, thanks!

Comment: the question is currently showing *no* indentations for `foo` nor the expected results, so ... do we need to worry about indentation at all and if so then please update the question to show an example of an indented `foo` and the expected results

Comment: @markp-fuso there is no indentation in `0.txt`, `1.txt` or `2.txt` (which is the expected result). I updated the question to explicitly show what the expected result is, thanks! And I don't want to insert indentation in the final result `2.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `foo` only occurs in a line by itself
- if `foo` occurs more times than we have replacement strings, do not replace `foo`

Setup:

```
$ cat 0.txt
The sun has its own light
foo
The moon reflects the sunlight
foo
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
foo
The following line should NOT be replaced
foo

$ cat 1.txt
source-text1
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
source-text-2
[(('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))]
source-text-3
[(('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))]
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v setsize=2 -v ptn="foo" '                        # setsize == number of lines from first file that define a replacement set
                                                       # ptn == string to be replaced

FNR==NR { replace[++rcount]= $0                        # start replacement string
          for (i=1;i<setsize;i++) {                    # append to replacement string until we have read "setsize" lines into the replacement string
              getline
              replace[rcount]=replace[rcount] RS $0
          }
          next
        }
$0~ptn  { if (++pcount in replace)                     # if we have a replacement string then ...
              $0=replace[pcount]                       # replace the current line
        }
1                                                      # print the current line

' 1.txt 0.txt
```

This generates:

```
The sun has its own light
source-text1
[(('f1','b1'), ('g1','h1'))]
The moon reflects the sunlight
source-text-2
[(('f2','b2'), ('g2','h2'))]
The planet Earth receives both sunlight and moonlight
source-text-3
[(('f3','b3'), ('g3','h3'))]
The following line should NOT be replaced
foo
```

Comment: exactly the solution, no problems!